# Are type-projection still unsound in scala3?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-3, type-projection

Scala3 has dropped general type projection because it was unsound:
It was possible to compile code which was failing at runtime.

(question edited to reflect comments)

Consider the following scala3 code :
[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DcGpqzfXQyaJfZlfjTAsRA)

```
class A:
    class X:
        def outer : A.this.type = A.this
    

class B extends A
class C extends A

val b0 = new B
val b1 = b0
val b2 = new B

val c0 = new C
val c1 = c0
val c2 = new C

val b0x : A#X = new b0.X

val pathTypeMatch = b0x match
    case _ : c2.X => "c2.X"
    case _ : c1.X => "c1.x"
    case _ : c0.X => "c0.X"
    case _ : b2.X => "b2.X"
    case _ : b1.X => "b1.X"
    case _ : b0.X => "b0.X"
    case _        => "ELSE"

pathTypeMatch // "b1.x" 

val projectionTypeMatch = b0x match
    case _ : C#X => "C#X"
    case _ : B#X => "B#X"
    case _ : A#X => "A#X"
    case _       => "ELSE"

projectionTypeMatch // "C#X" !!!

val failingTypeMatch = b0x match
    case cx : C#X =>
        val c : C = cx.outer // Fails at runtime
```

Code compiles, but fails at runtime with "class B cannot be cast to class C".

The compiler considers `C#X` and `B#X` erasures to be `A#X`, so that `case cx:C#X` branch matches. From there, it is legitimate to consider `cx.outer` to be a `C` (which is wrong), hence the exception.

No warning is issued.
No TypeTest is involved.

When looking into the bytecode of `projectionTypeMatch`, the test of all 3 branches is strictly identical.

In [type-patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns):

> (A type-pattern T is ...) a reference to a class `C`, `p.C`, or `T#C`.
> This type pattern matches any non-null instance of the given class.
> Note that the prefix of the class, if it exists, is relevant for
> determining class instances.

Indeed, when the match is done against *path-dependent types*, the behavior is the expected one (`pathTypeMatch` is `b1.x`). In particular, the compiler had to take X outer into account in the match.

One would expect the match against *projection-types* to be consistent, isn't it ?

What is the intention ?

It seems the restriction of type projections to concrete types in scala3 would allow a consistent behavior. Is it so ?

Comment: *"no casts involved"* Pattern matching involves casts

Comment: @DmytroMitin "pattern matching involves casts". Yes sure, but aren't those expected to be safe ? Question edited to reflect the point.

Comment: `case bx : B#X =>` is a runtime check using `isInstanceOf` underneath. But this is instance of works on something which is similar to type erasure if not qualify as one (`ax.isInstanceOf[A$X]` or similar, whether it's `B` or `C` doesn't matter as `X` was defined in `A`). So you have a always-passing runtime test (like with generics and matching for type parameter) after which you have code that cannot be casted into what you want it to cast. Try providing `TypeTest[A#X, B#X]`instance which would check the type of `X`'s parent's type, if compiler picks it, it would prevent the runtime error.

Comment: @Jean-JacquesLecler *"Yes sure, but aren't those expected to be safe ?"* I guess, generally no. https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns "Types which are not of one of the forms described above are also accepted as type patterns. However, such type patterns will be translated to their **erasure**. The Scala compiler will issue an "unchecked" warning for these patterns to flag the possible loss of type-safety."

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok thank you for the tip, I'll give it a try. // I guess ``ax.isInstanceOf[A$X]``

Comment: @DmytroMitin [link](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#type-erasure) _The erasure of a type projection T#x is |T|#x._  Here T is a concrete type (mandatory in scala3), so |T| is T, isn't it ? Besides, no warning is issued.

Comment: @Jean-JacquesLecler *"so |T| is T, isn't it ?"* The compiler thinks differently. In Scala 2 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eoDYrqe3QKSjzE8dkayYBA The erasure of `B#X` and `C#X` is `A#X`. I guess this is correct. There is the only class `A$X` so in bytecode `A#X`, `B#X`, `C#X` are indistinguishable. Maybe there is inconsistency in the spec here.

Comment: @Jean-JacquesLecler *"Are type-projection still unsound in scala3?"* Well, not type projections themselves but pattern matching with type patterns using type projections. It is missing `unchecked` warning.

Comment: @DmytroMitin. Yes the compiler clearly erases `B#X`  and `C#X` to `A#X`. There is an inconsistency between the spec and the compiler, but I suspect the **compiler** is wrong, probably in the transition process from scala2.
 [type-patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns) suggests prefixes are taken into account in the matching. 
Indeed : [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/34GQhV7ORQOdSbeW7fbWdA)  `pathTypeMatch` behaves as expected. The compiler considers X outer in the match. Why would projection match be different ?

Comment: Scala 3 is missing a lot of useful checks from Scala 2 and they are being added. I'd suggest reporting this as an bug to Scala 3 team so that they would make this code emit a warning.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Bug reported: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/16728 let's see their position.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, regarding your suggestion of providing a `TypeTest[A#X,B#X]`. As of today, `TypeTest[]`s only apply to *abstract* types, *not* to parameterized classes, nor type applications.  See https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/12668 . In the described case `B#X` is a concrete inner class, the compiler doe not lookup for a given `TypeTest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/16728.

Fixed by https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/17136

The observed behavior did not reflect intention.
**scala3** compiler has been fixed: `3.3.1-RC1-bin-20230327-a569057-NIGHTLY` behaves as expected.

Note the faulty behavior may be seen as a flavor of *general type projection* unsoundness, and cannot be fixed in **scala2**.